# React-Native FlatList doest not scroll on Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am building an app in which I have a view dat displays a horizontal FlatList. The number of columns equals the amount of items I have in my datasource as I want all data to be displayed in one row.

On iOS, this works fine. On Android, however, I cannot scroll the FlatList even though I can see that there are items with part of their content outside of the visible frame. I have made a custom component for my CollectionView-like FlatLists, which I called `CollectionView`

Here is the render function of the component in which I encounter the problem, which I named CategoryOverview. It contains a background and several accessory views which are all pre-generated (you can see them in the {brackets}), and my `CollectionView`

```
renderCollectionItem(category) {
    return <CategoryButton category={category} style={height: Dimensions.get('screen').height * 0.65, width: Dimensions.get('screen').width * 0.35, backgroundColor: 'transparent',} onPress={() => this.categoryPressed(category)} />
}


render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {Renderer.getInstance().renderBackground()} 
                {this.stage}

                <CollectionView style={{left: Renderer.getInstance().sideCurtainWidth(), width: Dimensions.get('screen').width - (2 * Renderer.getInstance().sideCurtainWidth()), height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.8}} items={this.state.categories} minimumItemsPerRow={this.state.categories.length} renderItem={this.renderCollectionItem} itemHeight={buttonStyle.height} itemWidth={buttonStyle.width} horizontalSpacing={Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.15}/>

                {this.topAccessories}
                {this.sideCurtains}
                {this.topCurtain}
                {Renderer.getInstance().renderNavigationButton(() => this.backButtonTapped())}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

This is the render function of my `CollectionView` component:

```
render() {
    var collectionViewWidth = 0
    if (this.props.style.width != null) {
        collectionViewWidth = this.props.style.width
    } else {
        collectionViewWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8
    }

    return (
        <FlatList
            style={{width: collectionViewWidth, flexDirection: 'row', top: this.props.style.top}}
            data = { this.convertToIndexed(this.props.items) }
            contentContainerStyle={internalStyles.collectionViewContentStyle}
            renderItem = {({item}) => (
                this.props.renderItem(item[0])
            )}
            numColumns={(Helpers.isPortrait() ? this.state.portraitRowSize : this.state.landscapeRowSize)}
            key={(Helpers.isPortrait() ? this.state.portraitRowSize : this.state.landscapeRowSize)}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
    )
}
```

I have already tested this with the layout inspector on and all the frames are the same on both iOS and Android. Also, There does not seem to be a difference in regular and production builds, neither on Emulators and actual devices.

**Question**
Why does my CollectionView not scroll on Android while it does on iOS?

Comment: Why is there a width in `contentContainerStyle`? And please post your `internalStyles.collectionViewContentStyle` as well

Comment: @AyushKhare That is just something I tried to rule out that that might fix it.. I have updated my code!

Comment: I am not sure if you provide a width to your FlatList then it might prevent you from scrolling. Give a try without the width, and are you using a `flex:1`  in your `contentContainerStyle`?

Comment: @AyushKhare I have tried to remove the width from my Flatlist but this does not solve the problem, and I am not using flex: 1 in my contentContainerStyle

Comment: Is the flatlist inside a scrollview?

Comment: @AndriyKlitsuk No it isn't. In my CategoriesOverview it's inside a regular View, and the CollectionView component renders a only a FlatList

Comment: if you remove the style and contentContainerStyleProps does this persist? can you show the styles you're passing?

Comment: Hi @RobbieMilejczak, I have tried removing the contentContainerStyle props and it does persist. the style props I pass in are the style props of the CollectionView, which I define with the component itself.

Comment: but did you remove the actual *style* props? My best guess is the `top` property you're passing in is causing the issue

Comment: yes I Removed the style props. Even when I comment out both the style and contentContainerStyle props, the problem persists. On iOS everything works fine. Keep in mind that this is a horizontal scrollview, so the any top-styling probably doesn't affect any behavior. Would you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that setting a `numColumns` property does officially not Let you scroll vertically.

Apparently, the `numColumns` property can only be used to determine an amount of columns that fit inside the screen boundaries. In order to be able to scroll vertically the proper way, one should set the `horizontal` prop of `FlatList` to true instead of defining a number of columns.